Scala 3 polymorphic extension method not working well with literal types
In my project, I'm using Scala 3 and I think I've found a weird case where an polymorphic extension method is not working well with custom literal types. I've reduced down the code so that I can show the issue with a minimum code:
object Demo2:
  extension [T](either: Either[String, T])
    def toOptionCustom: Option[T] = either.fold(_ => None, Some(_))

  type MyValue = "value1" | "value2" | "value3"
  val myValues: List[MyValue] = List("value1", "value2", "value3")
  def toMyValue(value: String): Either[String, MyValue] = myValues.find(_.toString == value).toRight("Invalid value")
  def hello(myValue: MyValue): String = s"Hello $myValue"

  def demo1: Option[String] =
    toMyValue("value1").toOption.map(hello) // this line compiles
  
  def demo2: Option[String] =
    toMyValue("value1").fold(_ => None, Some(_)).map(hello) // this line also compiles
  
  def demo3: Option[String] =
    toMyValue("value1").toOptionCustom.map(hello) // but this line doesn't compile


The compiler fails to compile the last line saying that the function hello should be String => String type, which is wrong in my opinion. It should accept MyValue => String type function and hello conforms to it. toOptionCustom method is basically my custom implementation of toOption and I think it should work. demo2 and demo3 is basically identical except that demo3 goes through the extension method. Am I missing something?
My Scala version is 3.4.2 which is the latest at the moment.

Scastie reproducing the issue: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/1VeCGsszShGby3hBvO4sJA/3 - IMHO this feels like a bug in the compiler, but I recall something about avoiding to infer unions by design... yet in this case it feels like it should just preserve the type.

The issue is related with the Singleton nature of your MyValue type. If you add <: Singleton to your extension type parameter it works fine:
extension [T <: Singleton](either: Either[String, T])

Type inference in Scala widens singleton types to the underlying non-singleton type. In your example, the underlying non-singleton type of MyValue is indeed String.
The following example showcases this specificity:
def foo[T](opt: Option[T]) = opt
def bar[T <: Singleton](opt: Option[T]) = opt

val one: Option[1] = Some(1)

val a = foo(one)  // (a: Option[Int])
val b = bar(one)  // (b: Option[1])

See also Singleton or SIP-23
Alternatively, you could get rid of type inference all together:
toOptionCustom[MyValue](toMyValue("value1")).map(hello)  // Ok

